# Spring data neo4j - replacing provided Date converters with custom converter?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I initially had my @NodeEntity class having a @GraphProperty of java.util.Date type. The graph repository APIs automatically convert that to long / string value and stores it based on my property type. 
As I wanted to import huge chunk of data from csv, I wanted this date field in my custom or pre-defined string format, say "yyyyMMdd". So I wrote my spring converter factories for both String -> Date and DAte -> String and registered them in the spring xml for conversion service. But unfortunately my converter was never called. Only the standard converter was called.
Later, when I wrap the date object inside MyDate class and changed the converter to String -> MyDAte and vice versa instead of java.util.Date, converter was called and the required serialization was done.
I dont want this MyDate wrapper around Date just for the sake of converter. Now, my question is, how to override the default date converter with my converters?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
static class TestConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Bean
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new ImpermanentGraphDatabase();
    }

    @Bean
    protected ConversionService neo4jConversionService() throws Exception {
        ConversionService conversionService = super.neo4jConversionService();
        ConverterRegistry registry = (ConverterRegistry) conversionService;
        registry.removeConvertible(Date.class, String.class);
        registry.removeConvertible(String.class, Date.class);
        //add your own converters like this
        registry.addConverter(new MyDateToStringConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new MyStringToDateConverter());
        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer saved me in my time of need! They really need to make the documentation for this bit much easier to find. How did you learn of it @n0mer?